# Is there any way to remove password from excel file?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, security, vba

Recently, I have received one excel file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1St4K3lhXNVO70AbDx9cqxivbHG2Q-TbP

I have forgotten the password of my file and then after I tried below solution but not any single approach work

1. Change File type made it .Zip and then extract that zip file but this approach not working because Microsoft made it more secure and that's why we can not able to unzip excel.
2. I have used some software that uses some brute-force and there owns technique but it's also not working for mine.
3. I have tried my best for fix this but unfortunately, I am not able to get any single solution.

If anyone has found out the solution for this then can please share with a community.

Is there any technique to remove protection?

Thank you.

Comment: I always keep a backup of the original un-passworded files... Have you searched on here - this has been asked before.

Comment: @downVoters Please at least care to comment where I am wrong

Comment: @SolarMike okay if someone provide the answer of this then please provide the link of an answer to me.

Comment: What use would protecting an excel-file be if the protection could be easily removed without knowing the password?

Comment: Search on here - and not doing so is probably the cause of the downvotes...

Comment: I have also tried so many approaches but not working then I ask a question here.

Comment: @ADMIN if don't think you understood my comment correctly. Basically the question you ask is "Is Excel file protection fundamantally flawed and utterly useless?"

Comment: @piet.t I got your point but is there any way to doing this thing?

Answer (score 1):

A minute of optimism: if you know nothing about the password and use a brute-force attack, you have one chance in a billions to achieve success. ;)

It is an Excel 2013+ file with strong protection. It is impossible to [decrypt](https://accessback.com/) such a file without the password as it was with Excel 97-2003. Only searching for variants is left. But it takes much time and there are almost no chances.

For successful cracking you should narrow the range of searching: use a password mask, reduce the number of characters for password generation, 
use a dictionary attack. And enable GPUs to increase the speed of searching.

Read this [article](https://passcovery.com/helpdesk/knowledgebase.php?article=47#three) and study the [examples](https://passcovery.com/helpdesk/knowledgebase.php?category=6) of range adjustment in the knowledge base.

But I will repeat myself: it should be a very simple password or you should know its structure.

Comment: Your case turned to be simple - your password is contained in dictionary "1 million popular passwords" - https://accessback.com/0916/i/dc132f.png